# Assigning value from Checkbox to a variable that isnt complete

Tags: android

sorry if this has been asked, i searched but didnt find anything. I am making a form in android and have some Checkboxes that i want to pass on if they are checked or not.
so i made the checkboxes and casted the view to checkbox so it will check any of the checkboxes i click on(Havent added the checkbox listeners yet). The problem is, when it determines a checkbox is checked i want to make the boolean that is for that box be true

EG when you tick the buy checkbox, i want the isbuyable boolean set to true. is this possible without the use of many if statements to set each one? 
I made the string variable nameofboolean which is the name of the boolean to change the state but not sure how to actually change that boolean now without a multitude of IF statements checking each one.

EDIT: To clarify, all i want is to set the boolean matching each checkbox to be set to true when the checkbox is checked. I just dont want to use a lot of IFs to do it if possible.

```
package com.Assist.assistme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class market extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
//UI elements
TextView choose;
Spinner list;
TextView buyrent;
CheckBox buyable;
CheckBox rentable;
TextView type;
CheckBox hard;
CheckBox soft;
CheckBox ebook;
TextView condition;
CheckBox new_book;
CheckBox used_book;
Button search;

String course_chosen;
Boolean isbuyable;
Boolean isrentable;
Boolean ishard;
Boolean issoft;
Boolean isebook;
Boolean isnew_book;
Boolean isused_book;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.market);

    iteminit();

    OnClickListener checkboxlistener = new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
            {
                String nameofboolean = "is" + v.toString();

            }

        }

    };


}

private void iteminit() 
{
    choose = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.market_choose);
    buyrent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.market_buyrent);
    buyable = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.market_buy);
    rentable = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.market_rent);
    type = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.market_type);
    hard = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.market_hardcover);
    soft = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.market_softcover);
    ebook = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.market_ebook);
    condition = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.market_condition);
    new_book = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.market_new);
    used_book = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.market_used);
    search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.market_search);

    list = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.market_list);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.course_choices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);                 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) 
{
    course_chosen = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
{

}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain clearly what do you want....

Comment: Do you want all the values of check boxes i.e selected and not selectd right..?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I basically want the boolean set for each checkbox to be true as it checked. @Pragnani yeah that's basically it, I want to set a boolean value for each checkbox to determine if checked or not checked.

Comment: you want to get all the values once...right

Comment: yes, i want to put the values in an intent to send it to another activity.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want something like this

```
CheckBox buyable,rentable,hard,soft,ebook,condition,new_book,used_book;
CheckBox[] checklist={ buyable,rentable,hard,soft,ebook,condition,new_book,used_book};
int ids[]={R.id.market_buy,R.id.market_rent,R.id.market_hardcover,R.id.market_softcover,R.id.market_ebook,R.id.market_new,R.id.market_used};
```

in onCreate after set contentView

```
for(int i=0;i<checklist.length;i++)
{
checklist[i]=findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

Call this method like this

```
String data=getAllcheckedValues();
```

Get all the checked values

```
public String getAllCheckedValues()
{
String checkItems="";
for(int i=0;i<checklist.length;i++)
{
if(checklist[i].isChecked())
{
checkItems+=checkItems+checklist[i].getText()+"is Checked"+"\n";
}
}
return checkItems;
}
```

Format the string according to your requirement.

Comment: It worked! I modified it to what i wanted though. Thanks for the help.